# Having trouble calling method from another class. The program either won't compile or returns a null value

Tags: java

This is how I am calling the method in MovieRatingApp class.

```
    movie1.getRatingDesc()
```

This is the getRatingDesc() method in the Movie class.

```
public String getRatingDesc(int reviewNum)
{
    String s = "";

    switch (reviewNum) 
    {
        case 1: 
            s = "Terrible";
            break;
        case 2: 
            s = "Bad";
            break;
        case 3:
            s = "Ok";
            break;
        case 4:
            s = "Good";
            break;
        case 5:
            s = "Great";
            break;
    }
    return s;
}
```

Every time I try to call the method I get an error: 
method getRatingDesc() from class Movie cannot be applied to given types.

When I change how I call my method to, movie1.getRatingDesc(int numReview) I get a different error. But what I really want to do is return the value of the variable "s" which describes the rating.

Comment: how come you call `movie1.getRatingDesc()` without the int parameter? from your example `getRatingDesc(int reviewNum)` takes an int as a parameter

Comment: The method expects an int as parameter, but gets nothing, so it fails. If that isn't the error, please be more specific.

Comment: The method expects a parameter of type ``int``, but your don't pass one.

Comment: Please make sure to always provide compact, easy and testable code in order to let others help you easily

Comment: My goal is to output the rating description ("good", "great", etc) that corresponds to the ReviewNum (integers 1 through 5).

Comment: Try passing an int.  `String rating = movie1.getRatingDesc(1)` for example.

Comment: Thank you Brandon! Calling movie1.getRatingDesc(1) worked, and printed the correct rating description when I ran the program. Now how do I pass in the variable so that I don't have to hard code the rating number.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass in the variable in your call.

```
int numReview; //declare numReview.
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); //Assuming you're going to have the user type it in.
numReview = sc.nextInt(); //Accept next integer from console, store in variable.
System.out.println(movie1.getRatingDesc(numReview)); //Call it, print result.
```

Note that error handling is omitted.  If somebody tries to enter text or a number that is unexpected, you'll need to be responsible for how that's treated.